# Margin of a fragment's root view not registered (when used in ViewPager)

Tags: android, android-layout

So I have this simple main layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/top_bar" />

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/VpPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I use a FragmentPagerAdapter to fill the ViewPager with different fragments, which works as expected, except for one thing.

Let's say one of the fragments has this layout, where window is an XML-file containing a simple shape with rounded corners:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_margin="16dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/window">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

Then, for some reason, the margin of 16dp is completely ignored. But if I set the layout to:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="@drawable/window">

        ...

    </LinearLayout>

</FrameLayout>
```

Then it works. I really don't want to nest the whole layout in another just to make the margin work. Plus, because of the background, I can't use padding instead. Any idea what the problem is with the first version? Any alternatives where I don't have to put the layout in another?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason for this is that margins are not supported by the ViewPager.LayoutParams, as you can see from [the documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/ViewPager.LayoutParams.html).

However, FrameLayout.LayoutParams does support ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams, which is why wrapping your LinearLayout inside a FrameLayout actually does provide the results you're seeking.

Comment: Oooh OK, thanks. So there is really no other way than wrapping?

Comment: You can try using padding on the LinearLayout instead, but that may not achieve the same visual affect you're looking for. AFAIK there isn't another way

Answer (score 0):

Set `padding` for `ViewPager` instead of `layout_margin` for the child fragments: you'll get the same effect with less effort. Of course, all fragments need to have the same margin.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <include layout="@layout/top_bar" />

    <!-- add padding here -->
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/VpPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:padding="16dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</LinearLayout>
```

The fragment:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/window">

    ...

</LinearLayout>
```

This has the disadvantage, that children are displayed without spacing between them and are scrolling in a padded space, which may or may not matter to you.